# I Text Sharp how to repeat header and footer

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

how to repeat report header and footer in everypage by itextsharp using PageEvent? I found the report header is not repeat if we add

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = new MarginalHelper();


 public class MarginalHelper: PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document document)
    {
        new HeaderInformation(pdfWriter);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Document doc)
    {


        ReportFooter(pdfWriter.DirectContent);
    }}
```

Header wont appear in the first page. Anyone know a solution for this?  i do not want to use a table for headers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, you should *never* add content in the `OnStartPage()` method, only in the `OnEndPage()` method. In other words: move `new HeaderInformation(pdfWriter);` to the `OnEndPage()` method. Also make sure that you declare the `PageEvent` *before* opening the document.